# Fine Tune SharePoint 2013 Page Load

Tags: 2013, sql-server, performance, optimization

In Development machines,all the page loads within a second whereas in QA and Production environment,each page load(even site content and site settings) takes atleast 7 seconds.

Help me with some tips to fine tune the QA and Production page load.

Dev and QA share the same SQL server and Production has a dedicated SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling Blob cache and re configuring distributed cache improved the performance in my environment

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check.

- Check resource utlization on the Web Front servers(CPU and Memeory)
- Check the same thing on SQL server
- Enable the Verbose logging and then Check the ULS logs during that time frame.
- check if Object cache is properly configured
- enable the Developer Dashbaord and check where it is taking too much time.
- check if Distributed cache working properly.http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/05/15/sharepoint-2013-page-loads-takes-a-very-long-time/
- Limit Noderunner's memory utilization
- Stop any unused SharePoint 2013 services
- If AntiVirus installed on the server make sure certain sharepoint folder exclude from the AV scan.

Useful reference: http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=168

Comment: By Stopping Distributed Cache service,the performance is good but stopping the distributed cache service will cause any harm to the environment?

Comment: how many servers you have in the farm? if more than one server then stop DC on WFE. if you have Social features in your SharePoint farm, COnfigured the MySite then all news feed type things need DC.

Comment: Enabling Blob cache and re configuring distributed cache improved the performance in my environment

Comment: great, Blob will help you in images.have you configure the object cache

Comment: Object cache is set to default 100

Comment: i think, thats all what you can do...how much the improvement

Comment: reduced from more than 6 secs to 2 secs

Comment: If this solve then marked answer to help others